# Set field to empty for mongo object using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document object that has an embedded sub-document.
To "clear" the sub-document, I try this:

```
obj.mysub = {};
obj.save();
```

This doesn't work, my object still has the contents of the mysub sub-document.
But this:

```
obj.mysub = undefined;
obj.save();
```

This does work, it removes my sub-document from the object.

My question is why doesn't the first version work?  What is going on in Mongodb / Mongoose in the first example?

[edit] Why doesn't the empty object get saved in the first example above.

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose sort of "protects" you from a lot of logic like you have presented in it's own internal resolution. So if you actually need to do this then do it at a lower level to the driver as in:

```js
YourModel.update(
   { /*statement matching your document as a query */ },
   { "$unset": { "mysub": 1 } }
)
```

And per the normal MongoDB logic then this will work and remove that level in the document that was selected. See the [**`$unset`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator for more.

Comment: Ok, do you know where I can read about these protection mechanisms?

Comment: @iss42 Well mostly under the mongoose documentation itself. You do really have to read it and not just spend 5 minutes familiarizing yourself with the general methods. But point here is that the two "different" forms do different things. If you really want to remove the actual fields from the underlying storage then use the lower level query form as given. ORM/ODM's are convenience  layers and not a "catch all" solution. Also not **my** problem. Take your issue up with a code maintainer. I just know the faults.

Comment: Ok, just trying to understand the reasoning for the implementation, could help me understand future similar such issues more intuitively.

Comment: @iss42 It's sort of a basic JavaScript concept really, if not baically just the same. Setting the field to `undefined` is not the same as removing that field from the object. To do so in plain JavaScript you use the `remove obj.mysub` statement. But working with a data store like MongoDB, you are better off using the native methods it provides to actually remove the data. Both should really produce the same result, the latter is better for wire traffic.

Comment: My question is though, why doesn't setting the object to empty and saving work in Mongoose specifically.  This does work in JS.

Comment: @iss42 I think that was explained several times. Empty is **not** the same as gone. It also does not work that way in any language. That should be very clear.

Comment: The object isn't empty *or* gone though when it has been set to empty *and* saved.  It is unaffected.

Comment: @iss42 Why did you un-accept this and specifically without making comment? I think it was clearly explained that you cannot expect that setting an object as empty or undefined in JavaScript is going to result in the removal of a field in the storage. As well I would not be hanging out for another answer because there isn't one.